# How do I push to a 2D array created with new Array() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push an item at a given index of an empty 2D array, but for some reason, the item gets pushed into ALL the indices.

If I explicitly create the array, it works fine:

```
const arr = [[], [], []]
arr[1].push('a')
console.log(arr)
// [[], ['a'], []]
```

However, if I use new Array, it's as though the reference to each index is shared and it gets added to ALL indices as stated earlier:

```
const arr = new Array(3).fill([])
arr[1].push('a')
console.log(arr)
// [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

Why is this happening?  If it's unavoidable, what's the best way to instantiate a 2D array in a clean manor, as with the second example AND be able to push elements to a single index?

Comment: That's because it's literally doing that. By using `fill([])` [you are telling JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to put that specific empty array instance in every spot. It's identical to `const a = []; new Array(3).fill(a);`, which you'd probably more easily recognize as putting the same thing in each spot.

Comment: you could do `new Array(3).fill().map(() => [])` or `Array.from({length:3}, () => [])`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans man, am I wrong to think that that is so unintuitive? It feels like it should be it's own entity unless explicitly stated as in your example.  Nonetheless, thanks for the update, that makes sense

Comment: @JaromandaX verified that both of these work, thank you!

Comment: @JoshLee I guess you are? It seems pretty obvious that `[]` is a non-primitive value, and so if you pass it to `fill()`, it will put it in every array element because that's what fill does, and if you modify it, you modify it. There's only one, not three (or however long your containing array is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you should fill the array with unique objects, use the map callback in `Array.from()` for example.
But if you fill a huge array you could consider `JSON.parse()`:

```
` Chrome/121
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 n=100      |     n=1000     |    n=10000    |    n=100000   
JSON.parse   1.00x x100k 137 | 1.00x x10k 112 | 1.00x x1k 110 | 1.00x x100 259
Array.from   1.97x x100k 270 | 2.31x x10k 259 | 2.33x x1k 256 | 1.39x x100 361
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/122
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 n=100      |     n=1000     |    n=10000    |    n=100000   
Array.from   1.00x x100k  88 | 1.00x x10k  96 | 1.00x x1k 127 | 1.00x x100 386
JSON.parse   2.35x x100k 207 | 2.05x x10k 197 | 1.41x x1k 179 | 1.11x x100 429
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let $length = 100;
// @benchmark Array.from
Array.from({length: $length}, () => []);

// @benchmark JSON.parse
JSON.parse('[' + '[],'.repeat($length - 1) + '[]]');

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it WAS using the same reference to create all the indices of the 2D array.

To solve this use `new Array(3).fill().map(() => [])` or `Array.from({length:3}, () => [])`